# error en getItemId() al crear un menu en el ActionBar

Tags: java, android

me he encontrado con un problema a la hora de crear un menú en el ActionBar, a ver si me podeis ayudar.
Para crear el menú estoy siguiente estos tutoriales:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dxeiq7CCjqs y 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvSgcUgrWjs

he creado la primera parte del tutorial con el menu_main.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_acerca"
        android:title="@string/acerca_de"
        android:icon="@drawable/informacion"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_salir"
        android:title="@string/salir"
        android:icon="@drawable/salir"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Pero luego con el segundo tutorial en el MainActivity.java me marca un error en getItemId()

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy siguiendo lo mismos pasos para crear el menú, y a mi me esta mostrando error, me puede decir alguien como solucionarlo ?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que versión de Android Studio utilizas? Recuerdo que en las versiones 2.x y anteriores pasa mucho que no se refresca la clase R con respecto a lo que escribes en el xml. La solución comúnmente es guardar limpiar el proyecto y reconstruirlo. Esas opciones están creo en el menú superior donde esta File.... el menú Build. Igualmente yo trabajo con Android 3.1 y el problema se ha aminorado pero sucede de vez en cuando.

Comment: Si pasas el mouse por encima del código en rojo android Studio debe de darte alguna pista del error. Posiblemente sea que la clase R no la reconoce o que no encuentra los elementos `action_acerca` y `action_salir` en la clase R.

Comment: [Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-studio/info) Utilizar esta etiqueta solo si la pregunta está asociada al uso, funcionalidades o problemas con el IDE.

Comment: La versión que tengo http://funkyimg.com/i/2AtPf.png es la 3.01 veo que dices que tu tienes la 3.1 no se porque no se actualiza, al pasar el raton por encima me muestra los mensajes que pongo en la imagen adjunta, y en la bombilla hay tres opciones que si las pulso ya no se que codigo tengo que poner porque el video no lo explica y como podeis ver no esto muy puesto, tambien he probado las opciones Clean y Rebuild Project y muestra los errores que tambien los pongo en la siguiente imagen http://funkyimg.com/i/2Aumd.png

Comment: @SoCu si perdona 3.0.1. Intenta comentar ese código solo el método `onCreateOptionsMenu(MenuItem item)` luego trata de compilar y ejecutar el proyecto, solo para verificar que este es el código que da problemas y no es un archivo xml o otra cosa.

Comment: Parece que el error se fue, borre los archivos y los cree de nuevo, pero lo que no consigo es que me muestre los iconos http://funkyimg.com/i/2AvCK.png que estoy haciendo mal ?